# Not getting console errors, but script is not working

Tags: javascript, html, svg

When I run my "app", I generate SVG code.

I've scoured the answers here, but am not finding my particular issue.

I am generating valid SVG syntax with the appropriate xmlns attribute specified.

I can look at the developer tools in chrome, and the body of my document is generating, its just not displaying.

If I copy and paste the generated body into a new html document everything works.

My code-base is too large (because of the library i have built) to share, but I will share the copy >> paste of the generated body as proof that all is working.

```html
<svg id="can" width="1000px" height="300px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <g id="rowStack">
  <g id="M001_header">
   <g onclick="eval(&quot;M001_cb.toggleCheck();&quot;);">
    <g>
     <path d="M0 20 0 40 20 20 " stroke-width="0px" stroke="#333" fill="#333"></path>
     <path d="M20 20 0 40 20 40 " stroke-width="0px" stroke="#888" fill="#888"></path>
     <path d="M2 22 2 38 18 38 18 22 " stroke-width="0px" stroke="#CCC" fill="#CCC"></path>
    </g>
    <path style="display:none" d="M3.055555555555556 32.77777777777778 4.166666666666667 31.38888888888889 8.055555555555555 35 15.555555555555557 22.22222222222222 16.944444444444446 23.055555555555557 8.333333333333334 37.77777777777778 3.055555555555556 32.77777777777778 " stroke="black" stroke-width="0px" fill="black"></path>
    <path style="display:none" d="M4 24 4 36 16 36 16 24 " stroke="black" stroke-width="0px" fill="black"></path>
   </g>
   <text x="25px" y="35px" font-family="arial" font-size="14" stroke="black" fill="black">M001</text>
   <g id="M001_ex" onclick="expandoToggle('M001_ex')">
    <rect x="120px" y="20px" width="72px" height="72px" fill="#aaa"></rect>
    <path d="M138 53 153 53 153 38 159 38 159 53 174 53 174 59 159 59 159 74 153 74 153 59 138 59 138 53 " stroke-width="0px" stroke="#333" fill="#333"></path>
   </g>
  </g>
  <g id="M002_header">
   <g onclick="eval(&quot;M002_cb.toggleCheck();&quot;);">
    <g>
     <path d="M0 40 0 60 20 40 " stroke-width="0px" stroke="#333" fill="#333"></path>
     <path d="M20 40 0 60 20 60 " stroke-width="0px" stroke="#888" fill="#888"></path>
     <path d="M2 42 2 58 18 58 18 42 " stroke-width="0px" stroke="#CCC" fill="#CCC"></path>
    </g>
    <path style="display:none" d="M3.055555555555556 52.77777777777778 4.166666666666667 51.388888888888886 8.055555555555555 55 15.555555555555557 42.22222222222222 16.944444444444446 43.05555555555556 8.333333333333334 57.77777777777778 3.055555555555556 52.77777777777778 " stroke="black" stroke-width="0px" fill="black"></path>
    <path style="display:none" d="M4 44 4 56 16 56 16 44 " stroke="black" stroke-width="0px" fill="black"></path>
   </g>
   <text x="25px" y="55px" font-family="arial" font-size="14" stroke="black" fill="black">M002</text>
   <g id="M002_ex" onclick="expandoToggle('M002_ex')">
    <rect x="120px" y="40px" width="72px" height="72px" fill="#aaa"></rect>
    <path d="M138 73 153 73 153 58 159 58 159 73 174 73 174 79 159 79 159 94 153 94 153 79 138 79 138 73 " stroke-width="0px" stroke="#333" fill="#333"></path>
   </g>
  </g>
 </g>
</svg>
```

My Basic generation of the SVG is found in a pattern consistent with the following:

```js
var svgRect = function(id) {
    this.id = id;
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;
    this.w = 100;
    this.h = 20;
    this.elem;
    return this;
}

svgRect.prototype.init = function() {
    this.elem = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','rect');
    this.redraw();

    return this;
}

svgRect.prototype.redraw = function() {
    this.elem.setAttribute('id',this.id);
    this.elem.setAttribute('x',this.x);
    this.elem.setAttribute('y',this.y);
    this.elem.setAttribute('width',this.w + "px");
    this.elem.setAttribute('height',this.h + "px");
    this.elem.setAttribute('fill','#888');
    this.elem.setAttribute('stroke-width','1px');
    this.elem.setAttribute('stroke','#AAA');

    return this;
}

var svg = document.getElementById('can');
var rect1 = new svgRect('rect1').init();
rect1.x = 200;
rect1.redraw();
svg.appendChild(rect1.elem);
var rect2 = new svgRect('rect2').init();
svg.appendChild(rect2.elem);
```

```html
<svg id="can" width="1000px" height="300px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"></svg>
```

The problem is: 
My code is not working **AND NOT** generating errors at the console.

I'm getting body generation of the code, and my "app" code is not working.

The example provided however is working, and this is inconsistent, but I have no reported errors to give me a clue as to why.

This is all running client side (Chrome).

Please help.

Comment: under what conditions is it not displaying?

Comment: I don't really understand the issue, please consider rewording/rephrasing the question.  It could be a timing issue as well, try displaying your script earlier in the file before other scripts.

Comment: Please state, **explicitly**, how you are creating this svg.  Are you using `document.createElement("path")` etc, are you making and SVG file server side and then embeding it into a page with something like `<img src="some-generated.svg">`?  Is it some combination?  Your question is unclear.

Comment: Updated my question

Comment: Just a quick note, but SVG lengths are supposed to be unitless values, and you are missing the `viewBox` attribute on the SVG itself.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I've tried that with no difference, so I left it out.

Answer (score 0):

I appended the following to my script and it worked, but it is highly likely that it is not the right answer:

```
        var myHTML = svg.innerHTML;
        svg.innerHTML = myHTML;
```